# intent not loading next activity

Tags: android

what are the reasons that would affect my intent not to load the next activity i've fixed my manifest the intent is correct the button is okey and the activity is good basically i don't have any errors or i don't see any can anyone clear these things for me i need help..this is my intent if you would like to check it

```
***Home activity***
package com.bpi.gears;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class Home extends Activity {

 ImageButton btn_profile;
 Intent intent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    btn_profile = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_profile);


 final Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(Home.this, Profile.class);
      btn_profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         startActivity(intent);
            }});
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;

}
}


 **MainActivity**
package com.bpi.gears;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn_login;
EditText ID_username;
EditText ID_password;
TextView message;
Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);

    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ID_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID_username);
    ID_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID_password);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID_login);


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if("".equals(ID_username.getText().toString()) || "".equals(ID_password.getText().toString())){

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,     "Please type in Username and Password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            } else {
                authenticateUser();

            }



        }
    });

}

protected void authenticateUser() {
    (new AuthenticateUserTask(this)).execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

private class AuthenticateUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Context mContext;
    protected boolean willContinue;

    public AuthenticateUserTask(Context context) {
        super();

        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        .....
 username="+ID_username.getText().toString()+"&password="+ID_password.getText().toString());
        willContinue = false;

        try{

            ....

            Log.d("Response",""+resp);

            if(resp == 200){
                willContinue = true;
                Log.d("doInBackground","Response is true.");
            }
            else {
                willContinue = false;
                Log.d("doInBackground","Response is false from try.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            willContinue = false;
            Log.d("doInBackground","Response is false from catch.");
        }

        return willContinue;


}

          protected void onPostExecute(Boolean willContinue) {

            if(willContinue){
                Log.d("Response From onPostExecute","willContinue is true, starting Home activity.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                /*Intent todashboard = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(todashboard);
                finish();*/


            btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));
        startActivity(intent);
                    }});

                }


                else{
                Log.d("Response From onPostExecute","willContinue is false.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed.",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

           }



    }
```

}

Comment: What happens when you debug and step through this after you press `btn_login`?

Comment: the log in is successful it displays the message log in successful but it stops there...it does not load the next activity it does not load my home activity..

Comment: Where is this message at in your code? Do you have a `layout` for your `HomeActivity`?

Comment: yes..everything is all set..the message thing is from the login code in the mainactivity...after launching it the plan is to load home activity if the log in is correct but home does not load

Comment: What `Activity` is this code in? I think you need to add a little more code to see what is going on because there isn't much to go on.

Comment: you mean the log in code?wait repost the code

Comment: it stops at the log in successful part it does not go in the intent part

Comment: It has to go here ` final Intent intent = new Intent();` unless you get an error here  `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. Check your logcat. Does it crash?

Comment: thats what im thinking ive been looking through this since yesterday but i cant find the error..somewhere in toast part..it does not crash actually when i log in it displays log in successful and stays in the screen...

Comment: yeah ive tried it codeMagic sorry it was an error but thanks you anymore ideas coz i basically ran out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your `onClickListener` out of the `AsyncTask` and put it in your `onCreate()` of your `Activity`

And change this

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
```

to

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

and put all of it inside your `onClick()`. Hope this helps...let me know

Comment: ive tried putting it on onCreate but i was an error it says unreachable code

Comment: If your whole `Activity` isn't too big then just post the whole thing because I really don't know what you have going on right now but I would like to help

Comment: Did you get it working then? Because there still seem to be issues like you creating a constructor but not passing it anything. Also, you call `super()` in your `AsyncTask` constructor but you don't have anything to override. Which doesn't matter because you don't ever call the constructor. Thank you for accepting but if you have more questions feel free to let me know or post a new question and let me know...I will try to help more

Comment: nope still can find the culprit...i've been editing in toast part but i have no more ideas

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having now?

Comment: is there an IM here?if there is none then il just post my question here thank you for helping out...im trying another one editing my manifest hope it work this time..by the way i dont know about AsyncTask to let you know im new making android just copy it on other post lol

Comment: I don't know if it will let you but try coming to [This Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26503/codemagic)

Comment: how can i type i cant find the text box
You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. lol sorry cant talk there

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about, sorry. If you want to post a new question with your updated code and the precise problem you are having then I will take a look

Comment: ***strong text***is there a layout which allows the user to make a menu on top of all the activity being called but the menu wont go i hope you can understand what im trying to say since i cant post a picture of what im trying to say here just picture out facebook's main command like home it wont go right?it is located above all activity being called in the screen... codemagic help?

Comment: It sounds like you want `action bar` if you are targeting I believe API 3.0 or higher. If not you can just make a custom title bar and use <include> for each `Activity`

Comment: actually i was thinking of making a nested linearlayout i dont have any idea about action bar but im going to try and make one if that is the best iption...how about a custom title bar?how can i make one?no idea on action bar and custom title bar...

Comment: I will be happy to try and help you somehow but they don't like these comments going on too long. Looking through the docs and SO questions should give you a good start on actionbar then you can post a detailed question when you get stuck. You can also search a custom titlebar but you can do it with your own `layout` then look into using `<include/>` in other layouts to include your title bar. Its pretty simple really. It just allows you to include that layout in another one. There is also a `<merge/>`

Comment: im into action bar now hope it works..is action bar just the same as custon titlebar?or they are different just the same result?in action bar i made a new layout in customtitle bar do you need to make a new layout or you just add it to your old layout?

Comment: See [This Link](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/older-implementation.html) `ActionBar` is an Android API started in Honeycomb, I believe. Creating your own custom titlebar is just a way to mimic that for older versions of Android. Yes, probably a `LinearLayout` then just `include` it in your `Activities`. With Honeycomb or higher you can use the actionbar so it can automatically include it in all your `Activities`

Comment: stay with me im working on it and i think il have a long way to go here il check it i get error i can fix....hes not showing on any activity i think im missing the call for it to show on activity...do i need intent to do call the menu?thank you

Comment: You're quite welcome. I am more than happy to help we just can't comment on this post forever. It isn't good for future members who need help. Try what you can, if you get stuck then post a new question with details and code and let me know and I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: LOL! I'm not sure how that happened. I didn't get a chance to answer your last question before you removed it. But you need to go through the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) ActionBar.TabListener and ActionBar aren't necessarily the same thing. You don't need a fragment. [Look Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) Go through the docs and start on something small while building your way up.

Comment: codemagic i think my mistake is just putting the word help on my question il make another account if its possible by the way can you check this out for me..http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/12/28/Android-App-Development--Using-The-ActionBar-Widget ive been trying to put it on my project but i cant load it i think something is wrong but when i run it on its own its ok but when i put it on my existing project it wont run....

Comment: if you see this message again codemagic and you want to help me please  send me an email you can see my eamil address right?

Comment: I can't see your email address. Your account privelages are probably just locked...give it a few days and you can probably ask again. And, yes, don't put "Help" in your titles

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more. this is the reply i get when i ask question..my email is martin_lloyd83@yahoo.com you think i can still ask or im banned permanently..putting help was my stupid mistake..